# Javascript Redirect - Keep Path and Variables, Switch Domain

Tags: javascript, redirect, mobile

I am trying to do a mobile redirect using javascript.  Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

Normal View:
https://secure.example.com/checkout/Checkout.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=456789

Redirected to

Mobile View:
https://differentdomain.com/mobile/Checkout.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=456789

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function TN_mobileUrlOverride()
                {
                    TN_mobile.DroidUrl = TN_mobile.IphoneUrl = TN_mobile.BlackBerryUrl = "https://example.com/mobile" + window.location;
                }
        </script>
        <script src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/TNService/Js/mobile.js"></script>
```

When I use window.location, it adds the entire domain resulting in:
https://example.com/mobile/https://differentdomain.com/mobile/Checkout.aspx?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=456789

When I use window.location.path, it doesn't carry the variables, only the file:
https://differentdomain.com/mobile/Checkout.aspx

How can I keep the file and url parameters while replacing the domain?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`location.host`](http://url.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-url-host):

```
window.location.host = "differentdomain.com";
```

Assuming you need `TN_mobile.DroidUrl = TN_mobile.IphoneUrl = TN_mobile.BlackBerryUrl` to all equal the desired url, do:

```
var url = new URL(window.location);
url.host = "differentdomain.com";
TN_mobile.DroidUrl = TN_mobile.IphoneUrl = TN_mobile.BlackBerryUrl = url.toString();
```

Comment: Javascript newbie... I must not be doing this correctly, can you please show where and how to do this?

Comment: @NotJay Updated with more relevant example.